# Overloading a function from a library

Tags: c++, overloading

I am currently working at a small and simple serialization-library for my project. This involves an archive calling a free template function that by default calls a save member function of T:

```
template<typename Archive, typename T> 
inline void save(Archive& a, const T& v)
{
    v.save(ar);
}
```

Now I want to overload this function outside of the library to support types without the save method:

```
/* A.h */

Class A {/**/};

template<typename Archive>
inline void save(Archive& a, const A& v)
{
    a << member; //etc
}
```

And in main.cpp:

```
#include "serialization/OStreamArchive.h
#include "a.h"

int main() 
{
    OStreamArchive<std::ofilestream> ar(somefstream);
    A a;

    ar << a;
}
```

So conceptionally it should work like the boost serialization library: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/serialization/doc/tutorial.html#nonintrusiveversion
The problem is that I don't know how I get the compiler to find the overloaded function. I spent the last hours looking at the boost code and I tried to find the trick.

The complete call structure of save is the following:

```
/* OFileStream.h */
template<typename T>
OStreamArchive& operator<<(const T& value)
{       
    serialization::commonSave(*this, value);
}

/* save.h */

template<typename Archive, typename T>
inline void save(Archive& archive, const T& value)
{
    serialization::Access::save(archive, value); //call T::save
}

template<typename Archive, typename T>
inline void commonSave(Archive& archive, const T& value, std::false_type)
{
    serialization::save(archive, value);
}

template<typename Archive, typename T>
inline void commonSave(Archive& archive, const T& value)
{
    //primitives get extra treatment
    serialization::commonSave(archive, value, typename std::is_fundamental<T>::type()); 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create a customization point which is used from within a template, it is being looked up using ADL. That is, customized versions of the function need to be found in a namespace associated with at least on of the parameters. Of course, you'd also need to make sure you don't call the function defining the customation point using a qualified call.

The special version of the `save()` should be found if you use this definition:

```
template <typename Archive, typename T>
inline void commonSave(Archive& archive, T const& value, std::false_type) {
    using serialization; // find things in namespace serialization if
                         // if there is no better version
    save(archive, value);
}
```